# How to snap to zoom with UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, zooming

I have a UIScrollView with a content view that the user can zoom in/out. The min zoom level is less than 1, and the max zoom level is greater than 1.

It is easy for the user to zoom all the way in, or all the way out. What can I do to get the UIScrollView to snap to zoom level 1 as well? Not just when the the user lifts their fingers, but as the they are zooming in/out as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a method, that gets called every time the user stops zooming, which then checks to see if the  current zoom scale is very close to 1.0 (like something between 0.8 and 1.2). If this returns true, the zoom scale is set exactly to 1.0 to snap.

Comment: That would work, but I would also like it to snap to the zoom level while the user is pinching, as an aid to zooming. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Why not then have an NSTimer go off every x tenth of a second (or so) while the user is pinching and call that same method?

Comment: I just tried that... it ends up preventing you from zooming at all unless you zoom quickly :(.

Comment: OK, I punted on snapping while you zoom, guided by the fact that be default, the scroll view doesn't snap while you scroll either, but rather animates you back to an acceptable position when you let go. I used this code:

`- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
  if (scrollView.zoomScale > 0.9f && scrollView.zoomScale < 1.1f) {
    [scrollView zoomToRect:scrollView.frame animated:YES];
  }
}`

Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to override or disable the pinch and add your own.  When you start a pinch gesture, you DO NOT update the display and resize the image until the pinch is complete, then issue your zoomToRect.